# Redirecting issue

Tags: php, forms

I have a problem with redirecting the page. i created a form to check users. there are two different kind of users.(normal user and admin).

if it is admin, le page will go to loginadmin.php else it will go to loginusers.php. it works fine locally on my computer. but not on line.

when I typed in the username and the password of the normal user, I have un error message
Notice: Undefined index: user in /homez.55/tzuhuich/www/development/aquarim/loginusers.php on line 7.

and if I typed in the username and password of the admin. it stays in the same page. I do not know why?
I need hand this projet to my professeur in early january.:_(
please help me!!!  thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

```
loginvalide.php

<?php
session_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password="root"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="aquarium"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="client"; // Table name



// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if ($result){
                $ligne = mysql_fetch_row($result);
                $username = $ligne[3];
                $password=$ligne[4];
                $droits=$ligne[5];
                $_SESSION["acces"]="oui";
                $_SESSION["username"]=$username;
                $_SESSION["password"]=$password;

            } 
// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
if ($droits ==1) {


header("location:loginadmin.php");
}else {

header("location:loginusers.php");}

}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>

<? 
session_start();
if($_SESSION['acces']!="oui" || $_SESSION["droits"]!=1) {
    header("Location:main_login.php");
}
else{
    $_SESSION['admin']++;
}

?>
loginadmin.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>page admin</title>
</head>
<body>


    <p> admin </p>
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="fomulaireajout.php">ajouter poisson</a>  </li> 
        <li><a href="modifier.php">modifer</a> </li> 
        <li><a href="suprimpossion.php"> supprimer </a> </li> 
    </ul>
</body>
</html>


<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['acces']!="oui") {
    header("Location:main_login.php");
}
else{
    $_SESSION['user']++;
}
?>
loginusers.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>page poisspns</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p><br />
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="pagevisualisation.php">ourfish </a></li> 

    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried `header( 'Location: http://example.com' );` ?  I'm looking at the uppercase 'L', and the space after the colon, and the inclusion of a non-relative URL.

Comment: stop using `session_register()`, stop using `$_POST` vars in your queries.  Do use `session_start()` and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: thanks for your help, i tried  header('Location: http://www.google.com');  it works. but if I change it to  header("Location: loginadmin.php"); it doesn't work and it says /main_login.php was not found on this server.   this is strange because  what I had wrote is loginadmin.php not main_login.php

Comment: Sounds like you have somewhere else in your script or .htaccess that is redirecting.  You may have to dig deeper into your codebase.

Comment: thanks for your help again. I find the problem. but there is new problem:(

Comment: i just edit my questions and add le new code. please help

Answer (score 2):

First use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) on `$_POST` variables. Its a security flaw.

Header can only be sent before any output is started. So make sure no output is started. Sometimes we just prepend " " before `<?php` and its tough to find. If All these are okay, header should work.

Comment: thanks for your help, i tried  header('Location: http://www.google.com');  it works. but if I change it to  header("Location: loginadmin.php"); it doesn't work and it says /main_login.php was not found on this server.   this is strange because  what I had wrote is loginadmin.php not main_login.php. I donot understand what do you mean by output et repend "" before <?php  can you please explain more ?  thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first items to check is, it it getting into the if statement? Try printing something out.

Next, are there any other redirects being called? most browsers will fail if more the  one redirect is being called.